# How can I use loop for all objects to teleport and also for random?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried first to use the loop flag on the line :

```
if (currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder >= teleporters.Count - 1 && isLoop == true)
```

IF the loop flag is false then I'm getting exception error on line 46 :

```
GameObject destinationTeleporter = teleporters[currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder];
```

If the loop flag is false it should make one round for all objects between the waypoints.
If the random flag is true it should move each object to teleport randomly between the waypoints.

The script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> objectsToTeleport; //list of all posible objects to be teleported
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> currentlyTeleportedObjects;   //list of objects that are currently being teleported at least once
    public List<GameObject> teleporters;    //teleports positions
    public GameObject[] groups;
    public bool isLoop = false;
    public bool isRandom = false;
    public bool isInGroups = false;

    public int teleportationsCount = 0; //the number of teleportations have been made

    [Serializable]
    public class ObjectToTeleport
    {
        public GameObject teleportableObject;
        public int teleportOrder;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (teleporters.Count > 1 && objectsToTeleport.Count > 0)
        {
            //at the start and every 3 seconds call "MoveTeleportableObjects" method
            InvokeRepeating("MoveTeleportableObjects", 0, 3f);
        }
    }

    private void MoveTeleportableObjects()
    {
        //Add new object to teleport queue
        if (teleportationsCount < objectsToTeleport.Count)
            currentlyTeleportedObjects.Add(objectsToTeleport[teleportationsCount]);

        //move objects on the teleport queue
        for (int i = 0; i < currentlyTeleportedObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            //Get correspondent teleporter            
            GameObject destinationTeleporter = teleporters[currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder];
            //set position of the item to correspondent teleporter
            currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportableObject.transform.position = destinationTeleporter.transform.position;
            //update teleporter order so next time goes to the next teleporter
            if (currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder >= teleporters.Count - 1 && isLoop == true)
            {
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder++;
            }
        }
        teleportationsCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go again Yasmin ^^

Code could be simplified, but I hope this time will be easyiest to understand:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

public class SOTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> objectsToTeleport; //list of all posible objects to be teleported
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> currentlyTeleportedObjects;   //list of objects that are currently being teleported at least once
    public List<GameObject> teleporters;    //teleports positions
    public GameObject[] groups;
    public bool isLoop = false;
    public bool isRandom = false;
    public bool isInGroups = false;

    public int teleportationsCount = 0; //the number of teleportations have been made

    [Serializable]
    public class ObjectToTeleport
    {
        public GameObject teleportableObject;
        public int teleportOrder;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (teleporters.Count > 1 && objectsToTeleport.Count > 0)
        {
            //at the start and every 3 seconds call "MoveTeleportableObjects" method
            InvokeRepeating("MoveTeleportableObjects", 0, 1f);
        }
    }

    private void MoveTeleportableObjects()
    {
        //Add new object to teleport queue
        if (teleportationsCount < objectsToTeleport.Count)
            currentlyTeleportedObjects.Add(objectsToTeleport[teleportationsCount]);

        //move objects on the teleport queue
        for (int i = 0; i < currentlyTeleportedObjects.Count; i++)
        {            
            //if flag is false it should make ONLY one round
            if(!isLoop)
            {
                //Get correspondent teleporter            
                GameObject destinationTeleporter = teleporters[currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder];
                //set position of the item to correspondent teleporter
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportableObject.transform.position = destinationTeleporter.transform.position;
                //so if it's not currently in the last teleporter,change it's order
                if(currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder < teleporters.Count - 1)
                {                        
                    currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder++;
                }
                //don't do nothing if not, to keep it in the same place
            }
            else //if it's true move it to random teleport
            {
                //Get random teleporter from the teleporters list
                int randomOrder = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, teleporters.Count);
                GameObject destinationTeleporter = teleporters[randomOrder];
                //set position of the item to correspondent teleporter
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportableObject.transform.position = destinationTeleporter.transform.position;
                //set the new order
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder = randomOrder;
            }
        }
        teleportationsCount++;
    }
}
```